# My app is not visible in the home screen of the emulator in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have been trying to run my app but whenever I run the emulator I do not seem to find my app anywhere. Is there something wrong with the emulator? or my app?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If there is't any error after running on emulator, and you don't see your app's pakage on the emulator, try to create another AVD and test on it.